# How to resolve @lwc/lwc/no-unknown-wire-adapters linting errors in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, eslint

In a new project I am getting eslint errors like:

```
6:10  error  "getObjectInfo" from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi" is not a known adapter      @lwc/lwc/no-unknown-wire-adapters
```

The relevant import statement is:

```
import { getObjectInfo } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
```

The devDependencies in `package.json` are:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@lwc/eslint-plugin-lwc": "^0.9.0",
        "@prettier/plugin-xml": "^0.13.1",
        "@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc": "^0.9.0",
        "@salesforce/eslint-plugin-aura": "^2.0.0",
        "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^0.10.4",
        "eslint": "^7.25.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
        "husky": "^4.2.1",
        "lint-staged": "^10.0.7",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5",
        "prettier-plugin-apex": "^1.8.0"
    }
```

And my `.eslintrc.json` is:

```
{
    "extends": [
        "@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc/base"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.test.js"],
            "rules": {
                "@lwc/lwc/no-unexpected-wire-adapter-usages": "off"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Through trial and error I found a config that seems to work, basically upgrading `eslint-plugin-lwc` and `eslint-config-lwc` to `1.0.0` (and downgrading `eslint-plugin-jest` to avoid a dependency version issue:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.13.15",
    "@lwc/eslint-plugin-lwc": "^1.0.0",
    "@prettier/plugin-xml": "^0.13.1",
    "@salesforce/eslint-config-lwc": "^1.0.0",
    "@salesforce/eslint-plugin-aura": "^2.0.0",
    "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^0.10.4",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": ">=23.8.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "prettier-plugin-apex": "^1.8.0"
}
```

I also set babel as the parser in `.eslintrc.js`. Not sure that has any bearing on the issue but wanted to include it for completeness:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
    parserOptions: {
        requireConfigFile: false,
        babelOptions: {
            parserOpts: {
                "plugins": ["classProperties", ["decorators", { "decoratorsBeforeExport": false }]]
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: ["@lwc/eslint-plugin-lwc"]
}
```